# How can I append rows from another table and also add a constant to another attribute?

Tags: sql-server

I want to append rows to a table. The first attribute will be from another table, using all the rows in that table, and the other attribute will be a constant.

```
INSERT INTO tStoreHistory(StoreID, StoreStatusID) VALUES((Select StoreID from tStore), 1)
```

I get this error:
Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Am sure your insert query does not generate that error check whether any other `Insert` statement is present or It could be because of `Trigger` present in `tStoreHistory` table. If you have any trigger on `tStoreHistory` table then post the code

Between proper way to write that `Insert` query would be

```
INSERT INTO tStoreHistory(StoreID, StoreStatusID) 
Select StoreID,1 from tStore
```

Your current `Insert` query will throw an *exception* when more than one record is returned from the `sub-query` (ie) when `tStore` table has more than one record